# iOS Charts: Showing grid with axis disabled

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm working with the [charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library but I'm facing an issue I cannot solve.
I deactivated my Y and X axis so that the graph goes till the screen margins:

```
mainChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
mainChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
mainChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 1.2
mainChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
mainChartView.xAxis.enabled = false
```

Nevertheless I want to draw a background grid. Is that possible?

This is my current graph:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to be:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got feedback from the library developers:

> grid background is not supported yet. We are planning but it should be
>   a long time. Either you change the source code and maybe a PR for us,
>   or just wait.